# Find the minimum number of messages that need to be sent

Tags: string, algorithm, optimization, greedy

I recently encountered a problem in one of my coding interview tests. The problem is as follows.

> Suppose there is a service to send messages to a user. Each message has the length of maximum 30 characters. This service receives a complete message and then breaks it into sub-messages, each of size 30 characters at most. But there is an issue with the service. It doesn't guarantee the order in which the sub-messages are received by the user. Hence, for every sub-message, it appends a suffix (k/n) where k denotes the kth sub-message out of the n sub-messages. This suffix is also considered when counting the number of characters in the sub-message which cannot exceed 30. Find the minimum number of sub-messages required to send.

Eg-1:

message: **The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog**

The first sub-message can be: **The quick brown fox jumps (1/2)** but

the above is incorrect as it exceeds 30 characters. This has 31 characters.

So,the correct sub-messages are:

**The quick brown fox (1/2)**

**jumps over the lazy dog (2/2)**

So, the answer is 2.

Eg-2:

message: **The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy tortoise**

So,the correct sub-messages are:

**The quick brown fox (1/3)**

**jumps over the lazy (2/3)**

**tortoise (3/3)**

So, the answer is 3.

Eg-3:

message: **Hello My name is**

sub-message: **Hello My name is**

Answer = 1.

**Note: A word cannot be broken across sub-messages. Assume no word is greater than 30 characters in length. If its a single message, then no need to use the suffix**

My approach: If the total character length of string is less than 30 then return 1. If not, then get sub-message till character count is 30, checking per word. But now it gets complicated as I don't know the value of `n` in the suffix. Is there a simpler way to approach the problem?

Comment: Well, you cannot know `n` without going through the whole message once, since you cannot know how it's constructed (15 character messages would be one extreme), so you need to "split" it into messages with placeholder for `n` (0 for example), get `n`, make another pass with real `n` (if > `9`, message boundaries might change), repeat until `n` stays the same. It's not obvious to me how you could do it in a different way, would be curious to see if one exists.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting this, I do enjoy these sorts of problems.

As domen mentioned above, there is a bit of a challenge here in that you do not know how many lines are required. Thus you do not know whether to allow for 2 (or more) digits for the message number / total message count. Also, could you use Hexadecimal (16 messages require a single digit, or even a base 62 format number (0-9, then A-Z followed by a-z)?

You could of course use a guess and say, if the input is more than, say, 200 characters, then you might use a two digit message number, but then if the message was a single letter followed by a single space repeated 100 times, then you could probably get away with single digit message numbers.

So, you might find that you need to run the algorithm a couple of times. I will assume that a single digit message number is acceptable for this problem, you can enhance my solution to use base 52 message numbers if you like.

My approach uses 2 classes:

1. Create a class MessageLine that represents a single line of the message.
2. MessageSender a class that collects the MessageLine(s). It has a helper method that  and processes the message and returns a list of MessageLines.

Here is the main MessageSender class. If you run it, you can pass a message on the command line for it to process.

```java
package com.gtajb.stackoverflow;

import java.util.LinkedList;

public class MessageSender {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("Please supply a message to send");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // Collect the command line parameters into a single string.
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        boolean firstWord = true;
        for (String s: args) {
            if (!firstWord) {
                sb.append(" ");
            }
            firstWord = false;
            sb.append(s);
        }

        // Process the input String and create the MessageSender object.
        MessageSender ms = new MessageSender(sb.toString());
        System.out.println("Input message: " + sb.toString());

        // Retrieve the blocked message and output it.
        LinkedList<MessageLine> msg = ms.getBlockedMessage();
        int lineNo = 0;
        for (MessageLine ml : msg) {
            lineNo += 1;
            System.out.printf("%2d: %s\n", lineNo, ml.getFormattedLine(msg.size()));
        }
    }

    private String msg;

    public MessageSender(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
        processMessage();
    }

    private LinkedList<MessageLine> blockedMessage = new LinkedList<MessageLine> ();

    public LinkedList<MessageLine> getBlockedMessage() {
        return blockedMessage;
    }

    private static final int LINE_MAX_SIZE = 30;
    /**
     * A private helper method that processes the supplied message when
     * the object is constructed.
     */
    private void processMessage() {

        // Split the message into words and work out how long the message is.
        String [] words = msg.split("\\s+");
        int messageLength = 0;
        for (String w: words) {
            messageLength += w.length();
        }
        messageLength += words.length - 1;            // Add in the number of words minus one to allow for the single spaces.

        // Can we get away with a single MessageLine?
        if (messageLength < LINE_MAX_SIZE) {
            // A single message line is good enough.
            MessageLine ml = new MessageLine(1);
            blockedMessage.add(ml);
            for (String w: words) {
                ml.add(w);
            }
        } else {
            // Multiple MessageLines will be required.
            int lineNo = 1;
            MessageLine ml = new MessageLine(lineNo);
            blockedMessage.add(ml);
            for (String w: words) {
                    // check if this word will blow the max line length.
                    // The maximum number of lines is 2. It can be anything that is > 1.
                if (ml.getFormattedLineLength(2) + w.length() + 1 > LINE_MAX_SIZE) {
                    // The word will blow the line length, so create a new line.
                    lineNo += 1;
                    ml = new MessageLine(lineNo);
                    blockedMessage.add(ml);
                }
                ml.add(w);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the Message Line class:

```java
package com.gtajb.stackoverflow;

import java.util.LinkedList;

public class MessageLine extends LinkedList<String> {

    private int lineNo;
    public MessageLine(int lineNo) {
        this.lineNo = lineNo;
    }

    /**
     * Add a new word to this message line.
     * @param word the word to add
     * @return true if the collection is modified.
     */
    public boolean add(String word) {
        if (word == null || word.trim().length() == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return super.add(word.trim());
    }

    /**
     * Return the formatted message length.
     * @param totalNumLines the total number of lines in the message.
     * @return the length of this line when formatted.
     */
    public int getFormattedLineLength(int totalNumLines) {
        return getFormattedLine(totalNumLines).length();
    }

    /**
     * Return the formatted line optionally with the line count information.
     * @param totalNumLines the total number of lines in the message.
     * @return the formatted line.
     */
    public String getFormattedLine(int totalNumLines) {

        boolean firstWord = true;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String w : this) {
            if (! firstWord) {
                sb.append (" ");
            }
            firstWord = false;
            sb.append(w);
        }
        if (totalNumLines > 1) {
            sb.append (String.format(" (%d/%d)", lineNo, totalNumLines));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

I tested your scenarios and it seems to produce the correct result.

Let me know if *we* get the job. :-)

Comment: If any of these answers has helped you, could you please accept one of them as the answer and "up vote" it. Simply click the little grey "check mark" next to the answer that you think has helped you the most.

Answer (score 0):

You can binary-search on the total number of submessages.  That is, start with two numbers L and H, such that you know that L submessages are not enough, and that H submessages are enough, and see whether their average (L+H)/2 is enough by trying to construct a solution under the assumption that that many submessages are involved: If it is, make that the new H, otherwise make it the new L.  Stop as soon as H = L+1: H is then the smallest number of submessages that works, so construct an actual solution using that many submessages.  This will require O(n log n) time.

To get initial values for L and H, you could start at 1 and keep doubling until you get a high enough number.  The first value that is large enough to work becomes your H, and the previous one your L.

BTW, the constraints you give are not enough to ensure a solution exists: For example, an input consisting of two 29-letter words separated by a space has no solution.